# What's the difference between !h and h! in float positions

Tags: floats, positioning, options

I know that "h" puts the figure at the place where it occurs in the code and "!" overwrites latex's internal parameters. But I don't understand why the order makes a difference. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: The order should not make any difference, it is just the existance or the chars that matter. Btw `h` does not mean `place it where it occurs in the code`. `here if able` might be a better mental image. Remember that `h` actually needs text above and below it (! relaxes the requirement).

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/82917, in particular the 8th section with the heading *Detailed placement rules when encountering a float*).